# Chrome 80: PWA not installable anymore

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am running a PWA which made no problems with Chrome 79. Now after upgrading to Chrome 80, there is no install-option anymore in the chrome settings dialog.

I recognized my PWA is not the only one. Many PWAs from https://pwa.rocks/ are also no longer installable in Chrome 80. However, not all PWAs appear to be affected by this: https://app.starbucks.com/ is still installable.

My app passes all tests in the lighthouse, uses HTTPS... Does somebody have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Installs for me on 80. If you enter this in the URL, do you see any previous installs? - "chrome://apps/"

Comment: What is the URL so we can test it?

Answer (score 1):

You should check. Is it already installed in your system?
I visited your app on chrome v83 stable and it is installable from the settings menu and the address bar.

After your app is installed into your system you will see `Open with` icon instead of install icon in the address bar. It is the best way to know is the app installed already in your system. And if your app is already installed you will not see any option in the settings to `install Starbucks`

**See the `+` icon in the address bar**

[image: See the + icon in the address bar]

**See the `open with` icon in the address bar**

[image: See the open with icon in the address bar]

This app `https://uitmpassport.web.app/` is also working in the same way in Chrome v83 stable.